# How to turn a mysql table with a simple parent child relationship to a nested set?

Tags: php, mysql, recursive-query, nested-sets

I have a large mysql table - basically a slightly altered LDAP dump.  120K employees.

The table is needed for lots of things but I have one task that is pegging the server - recursive queries.  Each employee has the empl. id and supervisor id on their row.  Easy parent child relationship.  However one of the applications we have is a mass email app.  And we use the LDAP table to search for all employees under a given manager.  Well this may go 6-10 levels deep and include 10-20K rows.  It is intense.  My current system is not working for large queries.

So how can I automate the parent child relationship into a nested set?  This is really beyond what I have done in mysql so any help is appreciated.

Also how has this not been asked 100 times?

Answer (score 0):

I built a stored procedure that does the job. This starts with a supervisor id and find all children and their children. Beware a circular relationship!

Assumptions: 
Employee table has PID (person) and SupID (supervisor)

Emailtable has PID, PersonName, Email, Nodelevel (int), starts out empty.

Call Nodeup(1,SupervisorID)  (parameters IN curnode int, IN supid int)

```
BEGIN
#Routine body goes here...
declare newnode int;
if curnode = 1 then
insert emailtable (pid,personname,email,nodelevel) select pid,personname,email,1 from  employees where pid = superid;
end if;

insert emailtable(personname,pid,email,nodelevel) select personname,pid,email,curnode+1 
        from employees where supid in (select pid from emailtable where curnode = emailtable.nodelevel);
    set newnode = (select max(nodelevel) from emailtable);
    if newnode > curnode then
        call nodeup(Newnode,0);
    end if;
END
```